# Android studio - How to make the first item in the spinner to be empty?

Tags: java, android-studio

As the topic says, how can I make the first item to be empty?

As it is now, I have a value at the first place in the spinner that always is chosen from the beginning. This means that the application goes to the second activity directly, and one have no chance to select another items in the list.

I have saved all my Strings in string.xml, in a String array. The code in MainActivity looks like this;

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_names, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setText(null);
        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(23);

        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        String txtFromSpinner = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (txtFromSpinner.equals("Denmark")) {
            //Go to Denmark activity
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

});
```

As you can see, the application starts with the MainActivity, but since Denmark is the first String in strings.xml, the application goes directly to the "Denmark activity".

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty string item on your string.xml, somthing like this:

```
<string-array name="country_names">
        <item></item>
        <item>Denmark</item>

    </string-array>
```

---

**Update2**

Or you can do this `setSelection(position, false);` in the initial selection before `setOnItemSelectedListener(listener)`

So update your code to this:

```
   spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_names, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    setSelection(0, false); 
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setText(null);
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(23);

            Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            String txtFromSpinner = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if (txtFromSpinner.equals("Denmark")) {
                //Go to Denmark activity
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you!I tried out that, but it looks wierd with an empty field :) 

Is it possible to chnage the code so it just igones the fact that Denmark is chosen from the beginning?

Comment: I tried your edited answer, it works. The problem now is that "Denmark" is already there when the application is executed, so if one would like to choose "Denmark", one have to choose something other first before "Denmark", otherwise it would not work. Nothing actually happends. How can I solve this problem?